# Node.js posting undefined

Tags: html, mysql, node.js

I am trying to post and insert data from `html` form using `node.js` but I am having problem posting data from `HTML` form to `node.js` and extracting the data passed it always undefined for inserting in database using `node-mysql` I am new with `node.js`

Here is my `app.js` code

```
var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var jsonParser = bodyParser.json()
var sql = require('mysql');

var connection = sql.createConnection({
 host     : 'localhost',
 user     : 'root',
 password : '',
 port     : '3306',
 database : 'node'
});

server.listen(3000);

app.get('/nodeThis', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/insert.html');
});

app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.post('/nodeThis', jsonParser, function (req, res) {

var post={user_name:req.body.name1,user_what:req.body.what,user_why:req.body.why};
console.log(post);

 });
```

Here is my `HTML` form:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div>   
            <form action="/nodeThis" method="post">
                <input type="text" name="name1">
                <input type="text" name="what">
                <input type="text" name="why">
                <button class="boom">Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you're posting from a normal form, you need to add the [urlencoded](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser#bodyparserurlencodedoptions) middleware too.

Comment: @Ben Fortune another question, lets say after i insert data to database what i want is to get total number of rows table has, and write it to a span in my html what is the best way to accomplish it? i really had no idea about this